# Change webserver used by Flex in FlexBuilder to .NET Framework 3.5

Tags: apache-flex, flexbuilder, webdev.webserver

I just had to reformat and reinstall Flex and reconstruct a project.

The problem is i am using ASP.NET as my server side technology and using LINQ in my files. The version of `WebDev.Webserver.exe` that FlexBuilder starts up is the wrong version so I get this error :

> Compiler Error Message: CS0234: The
>   type or namespace name 'Linq' does not
>   exist in the namespace 'System' (are
>   you missing an assembly reference?)
>
> Microsoft (R) Visual C# 2005 Compiler
>   version 8.00.50727.3053 for Microsoft
>   (R) Windows (R) 2005 Framework version
>   2.0.50727 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2001-2005. All rights
>   reserved.

I know that changing to the latest version of ASP.NET / Framework will fix this - but I just can't figure out HOW to make that change in Flexbuilder. I cant even remember if i ever successfully did it before or if I just created a virtual directory in IIS7.

Where would I change the version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I only had a very minimal `web.config` file set up.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Once I opened the project in Visual Studio (which I hadn't done) - it upgraded the web.config to one of those really long ones and then the 3.5 framework was used. I didn't have to make any changes in the Flex environment.